# Unable to import argparse 1.2.1 for python 2.5 on windows

Tags: windows, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse, python-2.5

So, I thought that I had correctly installed the setuptools and argparse 1.2.1.

```
C:\Python25_64bit>python ez_setup.py argparse
Searching for argparse
Best match: argparse 1.2.1
Processing argparse-1.2.1-py2.5.egg
argparse 1.2.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using c:\python25_64bit\lib\site-packages\argparse-1.2.1-py2.5.egg
Processing dependencies for argparse
Finished processing dependencies for argparse

C:\Python25_64bit>python
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Dec 23 2008, 15:19:34) [MSC v.1400 64 bit (AMD64)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import argparse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named argparse
>>> quit()
```

However, it seems that I can't import it, as you can see above.  I also tried directly adding the egg to my Eclipse PyDev projects, but this was to no avail, either.  As you can see, nothing is set in my environment.  Perhaps, this is the problem?

```
C:\Python25_64bit>echo %PYTHONPATH%
%PYTHONPATH%

C:\Python25_64bit>echo %PYTHONHOME%
%PYTHONHOME%
```

Comment: I always assumed that Lib/site-packages was part of the import search path.  Is this incorrect?      `C:\Python25_64bit\Lib\site-packages>dir  
 ...  
 Directory of C:\Python25_64bit\Lib\site-packages  
  
08/28/2012  05:41 PM    <DIR>          .  
08/28/2012  05:41 PM    <DIR>          ..  
08/27/2012  10:55 AM            21,499 argparse-1.2.1-py2.5.egg  `

Answer (score 0):

I hope you paid attention while installing and noted where `argparse` was installed.
In your script (run from the commandline or from your IDE) include at the top:

```
import sys
for p in sys.path:
    print repr(p)
```

to see all the paths python is searching through. Either add the path to argparse using:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/your/path/to/argparse')
```

or move the install to something in the path.

The environment variables can be empty, there are compiled in elements for `sys.path` as well.